# Tensorboard : Unable to update graph

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am learning TensorFlow and attempting to use TensorBoard to visualize my work.
However, when I try to visualize in TensorBoard, I only see an empty board.

Here's what I'm doing:

1. Create Event file with default graph object

   ```
   import tensorflow as tf
   g = tf.get_default_graph()
   evt_file = tf.summary.FileWriter('test')
   evt_file.add_graph(g)
   ```
2. add ops to default graph

   ```
   input_value = tf.constant(1.5, name='const')
   w1 = tf.Variable(0.8, name='var1')
   ```
3. add updated graph to the event file (Is this step even needed to update event file, even though I already added the graph in step1 above?)

   ```
   evt_file.add_graph(g)
   ```

I waited long enough for everything to be written to the disk (instead using evt_file.flush()) but the board is still empty.
The FileWriter constructor method has a param, **flush_secs = 120**.

> flush_secs: Number. How often, in seconds, to flush the pending events and summaries to disk.

So I thought that the file would update if I waited long enough (and not force update with writer.flush())

I am using Chrome.

[image]

Comment: Did you try looking at the output graphdef file on disk to check that it is getting written as expected?

Comment: thx for the suggestion. the modified date/time of the file doesn't change. That's why bit confused - despite flush_secs = 120, why event filed doesn't get updated after waiting long!

Comment: Maybe try forcing a flush to make sure it works then, or try reducing the flush time to 1 second, to make sure something else isn't wrong?

Comment: Any update on this? Did you try forcing the flush or reducing the time?

Comment: actually I realise any tensor / ops added to graph subsequent to first evt_file.add_graph(g) statement do not appear in tensor board (even if I do flush(). I HAVE to do add_graph() again to add any new tensor / ops into TensorBoard